# PWM on Pin 4 - arduino Micro

Tags: pins, pwm, timers, arduino-micro

I am using Arduino Micro. Is there any way to use PWM on pin 4 instead of Pin3 ?

I tried to change pins_Arduino.h but didnt worked.

```
//#define digitalPinHasPWM(p)         ((p) == 3 || (p) == 5 || (p) == 6 || (p) == 9 || (p) == 10 || (p) == 11 || (p) == 13)

#define digitalPinHasPWM(p)         ((p) == 4 || (p) == 5 || (p) == 6 || (p) == 9 || (p) == 10 || (p) == 11 || (p) == 13)
```

and

```
const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_timer_PGM[] = {
    NOT_ON_TIMER,   
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    ////////////////////////modified///////////////
    //TIMER0B,      /* 3 */
    //NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    TIMER0B,        /* 4 */
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    TIMER3A,        /* 5 */
    TIMER4D,        /* 6 */
    NOT_ON_TIMER,   

    NOT_ON_TIMER,   
    TIMER1A,        /* 9 */
    TIMER1B,        /* 10 */
    TIMER0A,        /* 11 */

    NOT_ON_TIMER,   
    TIMER4A,        /* 13 */

    NOT_ON_TIMER,   
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,

    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
    NOT_ON_TIMER,
};
```

Comment: @Majenko has answered your question.  What many do not realize is that there are many Aruidno boards with a number of different processors.  It is difficult to make them all work alike.  That is, using the "Arduino set of software" (Libraries, boot loaders, ect), it is difficult to abstract the hardware to make all Arduino boards act exactly like the original Arduino Uno.  I think you can do what you want on an Arduino Mega board.

Comment: i am willing to modify the abstraction layers. Just want to make sure that it will work if i modify the libraries

Comment: The Micro layout: http://www.pighixxx.com/test/portfolio-items/micro/

Comment: You need to understand both the hardware and software before starting.  It may be that no matter what you do there isn't PWM hardware on pin 4 of the micro you are using.  However, if you understand what you goals are you may be able to implement a software PWM.  But, likely, you would have to use interrupts for timing.  And that might interfere with other Arduino features / functions.  At some point it may just be easier to use a more feature rich micro.  Especially if this is a one off project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. There is no PWM on that pin. PWM is generated by hardware. The hardware simply does not exist.

Comment: even something slimier to 'Software Serial' not available?

Comment: Software PWM is possible but quite intensive. Servo.h does it but only for very low duty cycles.

Comment: my intention is to control a dc motor driver(TB6612FNG)  that needs  PWM inputs

Comment: You get glitches is software PWM which makes it a poor choice for motor control.

Comment: sad to hear that, and thank you so much for your support

Comment: You can get external PWM generating cards.

Comment: For a simple and bad quality motor in a toy, then software PWM is possible. Are there ways to free a PWM pin by changing the way the pins are connected ?

Comment: It depends what else you want to be doing at the same time.